# Issues establishing a connection to Azure SQL Database using Connection string via a WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, wcf, azure

I'm having trouble connecting to a SQL Database hosted on Azure, via a WCF Service I created. I got the connection string from Azure itself by clicking on the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGY6q.png).

Things i have done:

1. Added the Public IP of my WCF service to the firewall settings of my Database Server.
2. Allowed access to Azure Services
3. Tried Connecting to the SQL Server via VS2015 by clicking on [Tools>Open in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u71Q2.png)

Here is my ADO.NET(SQL authentication) Connection string if it helps:

> Server=tcp:thebutlrserver.database.windows.net,1433;Data Source=thebutlrserver.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=btlrDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=******;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=120;

The Error I'm getting is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: are you facing this issue consistently or at times ?

Comment: did you verify that you can resolve the server DNS ?

Comment: @TheGameiswar - This is the first time Ive tried setting things up.

Comment: @Aravind - Im not sure how to Accomplish that.

Comment: @gys see if you are able to ping that server and also see if you can telnet to that vm on 1433 port.

Comment: @Aravind Thanks for the Instructions. When pinged the Requests timeout. When using telnet to check the port it says Connection Failed.

Comment: @Aravind - I added a firewall on my pc for 191.237.232.75 1433, but i still unable to telnet the ip/port. Or ping the ip.

Comment: In azure VMs you can't ping the ip. You'll ping the dns name and it'll be resolved to an ip. If you can't telnet then there is some access issue and that's why you are not able to connect to the dB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi all i was able to fix this issue by Going to Uninstall or change a program> Turn Windows features on or off> en just enabling everything